# Updating sort-order values using jquery-ui's sortable widget

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a view which displays a couple of `divs`. These `divs` are sortable/draggable using [jquery-ui's sortable widget](https://jqueryui.com/sortable/).
I am trying to update the value of an input field based on the position of the div. However, I only got this far: I am updating the `html` of whole `div` instead of updating `value` of the containing input field. Which would be the best selector to use to update the `value` of input fields instead of the the entire div's html?

**HTML**

```
<div id="sortable" class="ui-sortable">
  <div class="ui-state-default">0<input id="sort_order_1" name="sort_order[]" type=text value="0"></div>
  <div class="ui-state-default">1<input id="sort_order_2" name="sort_order[]" type=text value="1"></div>
  <div class="ui-state-default">2<input id="sort_order_3" name="sort_order[]" type=text value="2"></div>
  <div class="ui-state-default">3<input id="sort_order_4" name="sort_order[]" type=text value="3"></div>
  <div class="ui-state-default">4<input id="sort_order_5" name="sort_order[]" type=text value="4"></div>
  <div class="ui-state-default">5<input id="sort_order_6" name="sort_order[]" type=text value="5"></div>
  <div class="ui-state-default">6<input id="sort_order_7" name="sort_order[]" type=text value="6"></div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
       $(function() {
          $('#sortable').sortable({
            start: function(event, ui) {
              var start_pos = ui.item.index();
              ui.item.data('start_pos', start_pos);
            },
            change: function(event, ui) {
              var start_pos = ui.item.data('start_pos');
              var index = ui.placeholder.index();


              cIndex = (start_pos < index) ? index - 2 : index - 1;
              ui.placeholder.prevAll('div').each(function() {
                $this = $(this);
                if ($this.is(ui.item)) {
                  return;
                }
                $this.html(cIndex);
                cIndex--;
              });

              cIndex = (start_pos < index) ? index : index + 1;
              ui.placeholder.nextAll('div').each(function() {
                $this = $(this);
                if ($this.is(ui.item)) return;
                $this.html(cIndex)
                cIndex++;
              });

              ui.item.html((start_pos < index) ? index - 1 : index);
            },
            axis: 'y'
          });
        });
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eL1nac67/)

I found [these examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16082519/updating-sort-order-during-sort-change-event-jquery-ui) on stackoverflow, but they are not updating any input field values either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is add the `val()` update inside the each functions. I commented out the `.html();` functions because they would delete your input fields.

Prev:

```
ui.placeholder.prevAll('div').each(function() {
    $this = $(this);
    if ($this.is(ui.item)) {
        return;
    }
    //$this.html(cIndex);
    $this.find('input[type=text]').val(cIndex);
    cIndex--;
});
```

Next:

```
ui.placeholder.nextAll('div').each(function() {
    $this = $(this);
    if ($this.is(ui.item)) return;
    //$this.html(cIndex);
    $this.find('input[type=text]').val(cIndex);
    cIndex++;
});
```

Sorter:

```
//ui.item.html((start_pos < index) ? index - 1 : index);
ui.item.find('input[type=text]').val((start_pos < index) ? index - 1 : index);
```